# Determine existance and values of multiple XPaths

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I am having:

```
<span class="class1">One</span>
```

or:

```
<span class="class2">Two</span>
```

or:

```
<span class="class1">One</span>
<span class="class2">Two</span>
```

So, there can be one of either elements, or there can be both. Using XPath, I need to extract the text from these. For that, for example, I use pure JS:

```
document.evaluate("//SPAN[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' class1 ')]",document,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

This works for any single node. I need a single XPath that extracts the text from 'class2' if both are present, or from the one that is present if only one exists.

The position of the elements is to be interchangeable.

So:

```
<span class="class2">One</span> //->One
```

,

```
<span class="class2">Two</span> //->Two
```

,

```
<span class="class1">One</span> 
<span class="class2">Two</span> //->Two
```

It goes without saying that I rarely use XPath, so I have little knowledge about them. How should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match element having class attribute starts with `class` like so :

```
//span[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' class')]
```

Or match either `class1` or `class2` to be more specific (formatted for readability) :

```
//span[
        contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' class1 ') 
            or 
        contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' class2 ')
    ]
```

Comment: Let me rephrase it a little. This code works as it is, but it returns the element that is first in the DOM. What if I need to get 'class2' if both exist and the element with that class is under 'class1' element in the DOM.

Comment: @larsonvonh then the problem isn't in the xpath bit of your code -if I understand you correctly-, it is the `.singleNodeValue` part I think. See example in MDN for a way to iterate through multiple result returned by `document.evaluate()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: I will try that approach and see if it suites me. I can not up-vote your answer since I lack the reputation, but thank you for the suggestion. Also, I will see if I will be able to find some other way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The iteration would be the way to accomplish what I need, but I am not able to jam it in the current process. For now (and probably for the foreseeable future), it is implemented like the first answer you provided so I would consider this closed. Thank you.